# VirtualBox messages

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

After I upgraded to VirtualBox 4.2.18 I noticed that my kernel log displays the following messages:

```
Sep 12 17:00:07 pc-allard kernel: [ 3721.553696] CPUM: APIC 00 at 00000000fee00000 (mapped at ffffc900110bc000) - ver 0x00050014, lint0=0x10700 lint1=0x00400 pc=0x10400 thmr=0x000fa
Sep 12 17:00:07 pc-allard kernel: [ 3721.553702] CPUM: APIC 03 at 00000000fee00000 (mapped at ffffc90011156000) - ver 0x00050014, lint0=0x10700 lint1=0x10400 pc=0x10400 thmr=0x000fa
Sep 12 17:00:07 pc-allard kernel: [ 3721.553704] CPUM: APIC 02 at 00000000fee00000 (mapped at ffffc900110be000) - ver 0x00050014, lint0=0x10700 lint1=0x10400 pc=0x10400 thmr=0x000fa
Sep 12 17:00:07 pc-allard kernel: [ 3721.553714] CPUM: APIC 01 at 00000000fee00000 (mapped at ffffc900110ba000) - ver 0x00050014, lint0=0x10700 lint1=0x10400 pc=0x10400 thmr=0x000fa
```

What does it means?

Comment: It means that your system is working fine without any errors.. :)

Comment: Ok, I asked the question because this never happened before with VirtualBox. Thank you for the anwser ;).

Answer (score 1):

I think that this should break down like this:

- `CPUM` means CPU module.
- `APIC` is the Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller that permits more complex priority models, and Advanced IRQ (Interrupt Request) management.

The only entry related in the [changelog of Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog) that could make this message appear:

> VMM: properly handle NMIs on Linux hosts with X2APIC enable

The concrete message is rather confusing, since the kernel throws lots of information that if one doesn't know the specifics one couldn't dream to know what they mean.